# Initializing a WPF-window with an optional parameter

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two Windows. Main Window and AutoImport.The main goal is to switch between windows, while keeping one window active and not closing it. I would like one to show while the other is hidden. I'm able to do this by using one window as a parameter in the other. The only problem i have run into is when the StartUp Window is the one with the parameter. I'm guessing this needs to be optional? I'm not sure how you would do this with a Window.

When my projects starts, Main window comes up. The code is

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private AutoImport auto;

    public MainWindow(AutoImport parent)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        auto = parent;
    }

    public void btnAutoImport_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        auto.Show();   
    }
}
```

If i click the button, the main window should hide and the other window should appear. Code is

```
public AutoImport()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    MainWindow main = new MainWindow(this);
    main.Show();           
}
```

Changes could then be made to AutoImport and when the button is clicked on this form, AutoImport would hide and a new MainWindow would come up. If the button on main window is clicked again, AutoImport would come up with the changes made earlier. I have no problems doing this when i switch the code on the forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do what you are asking you could just add another constructor to MainWindow:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private AutoImport auto;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MainWindow(AutoImport parent)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        auto = parent;
    }

    public void btnAutoImport_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        if (auto == null) { auto = new AutoImport(); }
        auto.Show();   
    }
}
```

Although I think it might make more sense to keep a copy of that instance of MainWindow in AutoImport since you are only hiding it.  So when you create an instance of MainWindow, you also create an instance of AutoImport setting MainWindow as a property/field of AutoImport.  Then when you click the button, the windows are swapped.  That way you don't have to create a new MainWindow every time.  Something like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private AutoImport auto;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        auto = new AutoImport(this);
    }

    public void btnAutoImport_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        auto.Show();   
    }
}

public class AutoImport
{
    private Window LinkedWindow { get; set; }
    public AutoImport(Window parent)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LinkedWindow = parent;
    }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        LinkedWindow.Show();           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as non-default constructor goes....

Besides the default constructor, add this one:

```
public MainWindow(AutoImport parent) : this()
{
    auto = parent;
}
```

`: this()` will ensure that default constructor runs, which contains the `InitializeComponent()`, that way you don't duplicate the code.

On the topic of your design approach, if you're not going the MVVM route, which appears to be the case, I would create some sort of window manager class that handles what windows are in the memory and their states.  By giving a two-way control to the two windows to control who's showing and who's hiding, you're creating very tight coupling and any changes are going to be a lot of work.  I say let the third party (another class) handle that sort of thing.  Why should one window know about the existence of another window at all?  If a manager is handling all the work or relaying data and another manager is handling the states, then the windows themselves only have to care about what they do.  Think of their responsibilities... what should they know about and what should they be able to do... certainly not the state of another window (in my opinion).

Note that I don't know the full scope of your application, so maybe your solution will tackle it just fine without over-engineering things.  I had a case where I needed a very basic setup, so I simply added a static property to each of the windows. I had that property hold the instance of the window after creation (done in the constructor).  If no instance was instantiated when I tried to check the property, one was created by the property. Basically, a singleton implementation.  So, whenever another window needed to access some window, all it had to do was call `SomeWindow.Instance.Show()` and the window would appear.  If there was no previous instance, one would be created and shown.  I allowed the property to handle all the dirty work of knowing if the window is already in the memory.  This also allowed me to access their data.  Very hackish way, but it was perfect for that simple scenario.

That's the wonderful thing about programming -- problems can be solved in limitless ways.